# Android timePicker 12 hour without AM/PM

Tags: android, timepicker

I'm new in android and I need held
I need a TimePicker 12 hour clock without AM/PM...
Is there a custom TimePicker like that?
Can I set the range?

Comment: I believe you need NumberPicker. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

Comment: i tried it but i need the slider :D and I dont need + and - buttons